# How can I make a textarea be spellchecked only when it's focused?

Tags: javascript, html, spell-checking

I would like my TEXTAREA Dom node to be spellchecked (i.e. spellcheck=true), but for the spellchecking to be invisible (i.e., no red squiggles) whenever the TEXTAREA isn't focused. I don't care whether or not the the spellchecking state is reset whenever the TEXTAREA loses focus.

From what I can tell, this is default behavior for INPUTs, but not TEXTAREAs, at least in Chrome.

I've tried setting the TEXTAREA to be spellcheck=false onblur, but that doesn't seem to help.

For content-editable DIVs, the strategy of setting div.innerHTML=div.innerHTML seems to do the trick, but I'm not sure how to do something equivalent for TextAreas.

UPDATE:

The following ended up working for me:

```
            onblur: function(e) {
              e.target.spellcheck = false;
              var old_value = e.target.value;
              e.target.value = "";
              e.target.value = old_value;
              e.target.spellcheck = true;
            }
```

Comment: Did my solution not fit what you were looking for Jack?

Answer (score 3):

If you're using jQuery then this:

```
$("textarea").on("focus", function() { $(this).attr("spellcheck", "true"); });
```

If you're not using jQuery, then I suggest you use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/).

**EDIT:**

The following code will toggle the value accordingly:

```
$("textarea").on("focusin", function() { $(this).attr("spellcheck", "true"); });
$("textarea").on("focusout", function() { $(this).attr("spellcheck", "false"); });
```

Comment: This does not seem to help, as I do not believe that resetting the spellcheck attribute modifies the current spellcheck state, just how changes in value are responded too.

Comment: So flip it around and add a second, `on("blur"` event.

Comment: @JackStahl I edited my post to reflect what you're looking for (to my best understanding).

Comment: Again, just toggling spellcheck doesn't actually change whether or not any works are currently underlined. Sorry if my question wasn't clear!

Comment: Selecting the text in textarea when its spellcheck is set to false will update (delete) the red/green underlines.

Comment: @JackStahl I believe that may be browser specific.  I could be dead wrong, but I've never heard of having the ability to control a browser's spellcheck in that way.  Either that or I'm still not understanding what you mean.